# Conda does not install that specific python version written in the environment.yml file

Tags: python, conda, version

I am trying to create a conda environment using the environment.yml while with the content below.

```
name: myEnv
channels:
- conda-forge/label/cf201901
- defaults
dependencies:
- python=3.6
- cycler=0.10.0
- kiwisolver=1.1.0
- matplotlib=3.0.3
- numpy=1.16.3
- pandas=0.24.2
- pyparsing=2.4.0
- python-dateutil=2.8.0
- pytz=2019.1
- scipy=1.2.1
- seaborn=0.9.0
- six=1.12.0
- joblib=0.13.2
- pytest=5.0
- pytest-json=0.4.0
- future=0.17.1
- pprofile=2.0.2
- pip
- pip:
```

but when I do CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda env create -f environment.yml in the folder that I have the environment file and I checked the python version I see 3.11.7.